# Safari can't open a secure connection to server

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, safari, ssl

intel iMac running Snow Leopard 10.6.4. There are several user accounts on this computer, only one of which cannot access https sites. Safari eventually displays the message:

```
Safari can’t open the page [url goes here] because Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server
```

Firefox and chrome also fail to display the pages, but they don't give an error message.

I have searched SuperUser, Apple Support, and Google, and I have found many posts but few solutions. I did try installing a new root certificate from Thawte as recommended in one of the posts, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: So, this is for ALL https sites? And not in Firefox or another browser?

Comment: @Arjan - "Firefox and chrome also fail to display the pages"

Comment: all https sites as far as I can tell.
Cannot load the pages in Firefox or chrome either.

Comment: @Chris, ooops, you're right! Can I blame that ugly scrollbar for that then? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I don't know if the current versions of Firefox or Chrome use the keychain for SSL. If they don't, the following probably won't help, but you could try running [keychain first aid](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9081.html) and/or [resetting the Keychain](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1544).

The quick fix may be to delete and recreate the user account (after backing up their data, of course).

Comment: The keychain stuff did not work, so I did the quick fix - gets rid of the symptom, but doesn't help me understand the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue , it got resolved when I unchecked the Web Proxy and Secure Web Proxy from System Preferences